# How can I get dynamic Timepicker values in javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I'm using Kendo UI MVC where I want to create a type of request. However, the number of user controls is dynamic and depends of how many requests of that type the user wants to make. So to create them, I have this:

```
@while(number!=numberAdds){
<br />
    <label style="margin-right:1em;margin-top:1.5em">Start time:</label>
    @(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
          .Name("startTime"+(number+1))
          .Min("8:00")
          .Max("19:50")
          .Interval(10)
)

    <label style="margin-left:2.5em; margin-right:1em">End time:</label>
    @(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
          .Name("endTime"+(number+1))
          .Min("8:10")
          .Max("20:00")
          .Interval(10))

      number++;}
```

And it works. Now, when I click the submit button, what I'm trying to do is to create an array of StartTimes and EndTimes so I can send it via Ajax Post to the controller. However, I'm not able to do so, because of the TimePickers ID. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
   $(document).on("click", "#confirm-request", function (e) {
        var date = $("#date").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
        var stringDate = kendo.toString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        var number = 0;
        var numberAdds = parseInt(document.getElementById("number-adds").textContent);
        var timeStartStrings = new Array();
        var timeEndStrings = new Array();

        for (number; number < numberAdds; i++) {
            var startTime = $("#startTime"+number).data("kendoTimePicker");
            var endTime = $("#endTime"+number).data("kendoTimePicker");
            var timeStartString = kendo.toString(startTime.value(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
            var timeEndString = kendo.toString(endTime.value(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm');
            timeStartStrings[number] = timeStartString;
            timeEndStrings[number] = timeEndString;
        }
```

However I can't get values for StartTime and EndTime, I always get undefined and I know it's because of  $("#startTime"+number).data("kendoTimePicker");

What can I do?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `number`-variable in the razor code (top code block) starting initially with `-1` (because of `.Name("startTime"+(number+1))`? Otherwise your javascript code will on its first iteration try to find `$("#startTime0")` without it existing. This probably leads to an error and thus stopping the execution of the JS-function.

So please check the names existing in your DOM vs the names questioned by Javascript and make sure, that they align properly.

Comment: the number variable in the timepicker is a c# variable which has nothing to do with the javascript function. As you can see, in the javascript code, I have var number = 0

Comment: Yes, but what if your c# variable produces `id="startTime1"` and up, while your javascript query asks for `id="startTime0"` and up. It won't find it.

Comment: Facepalm to me... How could I miss that one? x) Thx!